# How to extract only ERROR logs from java log file?

Tags: java, logging

I am working on log monitoring Application i need to get only ERROR level logs from a file called CATALINA.OUT. There are so many logs in that, only i need to fetch ERROR log level[entire Exception] from this. Please help me regarding this.

Comment: have you tried `grep ERROR`?

Comment: I tried with java.util.regex.Pattern.But from pattern matching i can able to get single line . I need entire Exception

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on linux, you could use `grep` from your terminal like so:

```
$ grep 'ERROR' CATALINA.OUT
```

From `$ man grep`:

> grep searches for PATTERN in each FILE.  A FILE of “-” stands for
>   standard input.  If no  FILE is given, recursive searches examine the
>   working directory, and nonrecursive searches read standard input.  By
>   default,  grep  prints the matching lines.

Answer (score 0):

To watch in runtime:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/tomcat8/catalina.out | grep 'ERROR'
```

Comment: i want this thing to be search from java and print the entire Exception. As i mentioned in the above comment, i am using Pattern in java. But i can able to print single lines.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a high level approach to handle this (supposing you don't have access to the logger configuration)

1. Observe the pattern of a log record (often the same so I took a jboss log):

> 09:42:55,142 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-6) Configured system properties...

So, the pattern to distinguish when a new log records starts is :

> TIME][space][LOG_LEVEL][space][classeName][space][thread][message

2. Implement a reader

To make simple, I propose you save log records into a list.

Below a simple algorithm for your reader:

`open stream
While end of log file is not reach
     reading
     if the line starts with the pattern “TIME][space][LOG_LEVEL…” then
          extract the log level of what you read until now
          if logLevel equals error then
               persist what I read until now excluding the current line
               create a new log record object
          else
               clear your log record object
          endif
     endif
     Store the current line into your log record object
End of while
close stream`

In you application ask to the user to load a log file and you can just execute your reader and display the result.

There is a lot of way to implement the reader, so if you are implementing a proof of concept, just create a reader in java which will read line by line, e.g.: [java 8 stream read a file line by line](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-stream-read-a-file-line-by-line/)

When It's working you can observe specifically a log record an extract exactly what you need...

Comment: Thanks, Manucci will try this solution using java Streams.